# Llamar a una función de otra clase

Tags: c#, clase, método

Tengo una función que coge una posición en un textbox y quiero llamar a esa función desde un botón de otra clase(La clase donde esta la función se llama "heredar" ,como debería realizar la llamada?

```
private void cogerPosicion(string punto, TextBox posicionar,)
{
    int pillarPos= txtBx.Text.IndexOf(punto);

}
```

Quiero llamarlo desde este botón que esta en otra clase:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Yo pensaba en algo asi pero siempre me surje un error u otro:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     heredar.cogerPosicion((TextBox)this.Controls["textBox1"], textBox3.Text);  
}
```

Comment: `heredar` es una clase o un objeto?

Comment: ¿Dónde están instanciadas las clases? ¿Son `Forms` distintos? ¿Quién los construye?

Comment: El titulo de la pregunta *"…sdfg"* no es significativo para nada. Modifiquelo para que tenga relación con la pregunta realizada. Gracias

Comment: @Xabier: es la segunda vez que vandalizas tu propia pregunta cambiando el título a algo ininteligible. Lee [ask] y vuelve a completar el [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores en tu código.

Para empezar, tu método `cogerPosicion` es privado, así que no es posible llamarlo desde otra clase. Debes marcarlo como `public`:

```
public void cogerPosicion(string punto, TextBox posicionar,)
{
    int pillarPos= txtBx.Text.IndexOf(punto);
}
```

Por otro lado, faltan parámetros en éste método (supongo que al copiar te faltó alguno,ya que acaba en una coma).

Y por último, en la llamada que haces, no coinciden los parámetros. Estas haciendo:

```
heredar.cogerPosicion((TextBox)this.Controls["textBox1"], textBox3.Text);
```

o sea, que le pasas un `TextBox` como primer parámetro, y un `string` como segundo cuando el método espera un `string` como primer parámetro y un `TextBox` como segundo.

Comment: Entonces seria algo asi?                                                                             
                                       
             public void cogerPosicion(TextBox posicionar, string punto)
             {
             int pillarPos= posicionar.Text.IndexOf(punto);
             }                                                                                                                                    Y la llamada asi?                heredar.cogerPosicion(textBox3.Text(TextBox)this.Controls["textBox1"]);

Comment: Si, si la llamada va a ser como lo haces en `heredar.cogerPosición`,en principio asi debería ser @Xabier

Comment: Sigue dandome error, me dice que "ninguna sobrecarga para el metodo cogerPosicion toma 2 argumentos".        He probado ha hacerla así tambien:                mailSpam cogerPosicion((TextBox)this.Controls["textBox1"], textBox3.Text);  Pero me dice que cogerPosicion se ha declarado pero nunca se utiliza. @Pikoh

Comment: `ninguna sobrecarga para el metodo cogerPosicion toma 2 argumentos` significa que tu método `cogerPosicion` recibe mas 2 parametros. Edita tu pregunta y añade exactamente el código relevante, porque con lo que has puesto no es posible que te de ese error.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, lo que podrías hacer es declarar una variable estática donde almacenas la posición y después obtienes el valor de la variable desde tu botón o desde cualquier parte del código.

```
public class heredar
{
    //Variable estatica donde almacena la posicion
    public static int pillarPos;

    private void cogerPosicion(string punto, TextBox posicionar,)
    {
        pillarPos= txtBx.Text.IndexOf(punto);
    }
}
```

El botón para obtener la posición

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Obtener la posicion de la clase heredar 
    int posicion = heredar.pillarPos;
}
```

Comment: Al final lo hice de esta manera y me funciono:                                                                      new heredar().cogerPosicion((TextBox)this.Controls["textBox1"], textBox3.Text);     muchas gracias por la ayuda :)